# Postgres: Simple SELECT * WHERE ... AND ... query fails

Tags: sql, postgresql, node.js

This query:

```
client.query({
  text: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE provider = ? AND remote_id = ?",
  values: [JSONuser.provider, JSONuser.remote_id]
}, 
function(err, result) { 
  ... 
})
```

Fails with `syntax error at or near "AND"`.

I'm unable to figure out why. Been programming all day. I think it's simple and I'm just tired.

Edit: Using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: Are you sure your db library supports prepared statements?

Comment: I wonder why using JSON to feed query to sql server. (Well I may not be aware of that thing though). If the query runs in postgre's query editor, then the problem is with the JSON library you are using. Also replace AND by && and try again. But what I think is an error with quotes. Because it is a SYNTAX ERROR. Sometimes a small thing might take entire day :)

Comment: I think Samuel's answer got it. I was using `?` when I should be using `$1, $2, ...`.  Will verify tomorrow. I'm using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres which does support prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which library are you using? I assumed it's Javascript and node.js. According to the docs(https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/README.md) It seems that you should use `$1`, `$2` for bind variables instead of `?`

Comment: Any idea what the proper syntax equivalent of `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN $1` would be, where `$1` is an array of values? http://www.pastie.org/3177014 gives an error like `array must start with {`  =^] thx

Comment: @JordanFeldstein it's probably too late, but using `Array.join()` in some form will help. Looking [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/lib/textParsers.js) could also be helpful.